# Why Xcode 11 beta can't use C++17's <filesystem> header?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, c++17

I need to use C++ 17's filesystem header for my project. As far as I know, Apple finally made it available with Xcode 11 and with macOS Catalina. I'm on the latest (beta 3) Xcode 11 and I use macOS Catalina public beta 2, so in theory it should work. But for some reason it's not, and Xcode gives errors like:

```
'~path' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15
```

If I set the C++ standard library in Build Setting to libstdc++ from libc++ these error emssages gone and I got a warning:

```
include path for stdlibc++ headers not found; pass '-stdlib=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead
```

and a ton of errors with missing iostream and cstddef in various files. What could I do to make filesystem work?

Edit: a minimal code example

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool isPathDir(std::string pathString);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string pathString = "../test.jpg";
    if (isPathDir(pathString)) {
        std::cout << "This is a directory!" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "This is not a directory" << std::endl;
    }
}

bool isPathDir(std::string pathString)
{
    std::filesystem::path path(pathString);
    return std::filesystem::is_directory(path);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a [mcve] that's failing and you can show us? How did you set up your project? Perhaps you need to add flags (explicitly or through a toggle) to enable C++17?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I added a simple example code snippet. I set up this project as a Command Line application, and added GoogleTest and OpenCV libraries to it with some opencv specific flags.

Comment: @DonátHorváth A "code snippet" is a *far cry* from a [mcve] - which is what was requested.

Comment: As far as I know, Apple no longer ships libstdc++ with Mac OS; so that really shouldn't be a choice in Xcode. I'll let people at Apple know. But that doesn't answer your question.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Fair enough, updated the snippet!

Comment: @MarshallClow Oh, thats answers the "include path for stdlibc++ headers not found" part!

Comment: Do you happen to have a back-deployment target older than macOS 10.15 specified? This would appear on your command-line as something like `-mmacosx-version-min=<value>`.

Comment: @LouisDionne Oh yes, that was the problem! As soon as I set the deployment target to 10.15 the code build perfectly! I've never heard of deployment targets before, thank you very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Promoting my comment into an answer:

> > Do you happen to have a back-deployment target older than macOS 10.15 specified? This would appear on your command-line as something like `-mmacosx-version-min=<value>`.
>
> @LouisDionne Oh yes, that was the problem! As soon as I set the deployment target to 10.15 the code build perfectly! I've never heard of deployment targets before, thank you very much!

Just to explain what's going on here, the issue is that support for `<filesystem>` was only introduced in Mac OS 10.15. When you use `-mmacosx-version-min=XYZ`, you tell the compiler that your program should be able to run on versions of Mac OS all the way until version `XYZ`. If you use a version older than 10.15, we nicely tell you at compile-time that you can't use `<filesystem>`, because that would be a runtime error (likely symbol missing from `libc++.dylib`) if you tried running the program on a version of Mac OS older than 10.15.